# How to display shell content also in other independent terminal window?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

One user is working on ssh shell. Root wants to monitor user's actions on root's terminal window.

I was thinking about connecting to *screen* twice.
Input and output is required. *cat .bash_history* is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [ttysnoop](http://www.linuxhelp.net/guides/ttysnoop/).

Answer (score 1):

By Anders' suggestion, ttysnoop is a great utility for this.  For something more permanent, you can try out something like [rootsh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rootsh/).  I have not used this as a default shell, but your sysadmin could easily test how well that works.

You can also look into writing a wrapper around the [script](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script) utility and setting that wrapper as the default shell.